# Typo in android:onClick tag in layout XML file not shown as error. Build completes without warning

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Developing an Android app with Kotlin and Android Studio 4.1. I mistyped the name of the onClick function of a button in the layout XML tag *android:onClick*, i.e. the function name does not match the name used in the code file (...kt). The build ran without error or warning, and the app was launched on the phone (emulator). However (no surprise once you know about the typo), the app crashed when the button was clicked, since Android cannot call the function.

Questions:

1. I find it irritating that the build completes despite the (obvious) problem. Is this expected bevahiour of Android Studio?
2. Android Studio does mark the *code tab* (red underline) if there is an error, but it doesn't do so with the *XML file tab*. Is this expected behaviour, again?
   [image: red,line indicating a problem]

Note: There is said error in the XML file as well as an error in the .kt file added for illustration purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From the picture, you can see that the xml CAN report errors, you just have to really *break* it. In this sense, it means that you have to type something which it cannot parse or make sense of, such as trying to define a property which doesn't exist.

Now, in terms of your button click listener, the xml doesn't really have any reference towards where it will be used, unless you tell it, by using context in your root layout :

```
tools:context="your_activity_here"
```

Complete example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.overview.OverviewActivity"> //<-- this is key
```

[image]

But, this will also still compile and install and you won't have any compile time issues here, so this won't really help in your situation

---

Perhaps a better approach would be to ask why you're still defining these click listeners in the xml, when kotlin offers us synthetic imports. Here's an example:

Instead of defining the click listener in the xml file, like you're doing, the following is also valid:

Assuming you have a basic button

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
```

now in the activity, you can just reference the button straight, by using:

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener { //this is the ID of the component in xml you're trying to access
      //your logic here
    }
```

This is because of a feature kotlin has, called synthetic imports, which allows us to directly access xml components by importing the entire file, such as :

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.example.*
```

---

Why I think this is better ? (personal opinion)

This creates an additional separation between the xml and the implementation - by setting the click listener in the activity/fragment, this file is now entirely reusable somewhere else, so we can use it in another part of our app without having to define the same listeners everywhere and by only making use of synthetics to handle your event listeners, you actually *will* have compile time errors, preventing you from building if a component isn't found

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning Android development with the help of the book "Android Studio 4.0 Development Essentials - Kotlin Edition", and this is the was I way told to define the on-click handler (actually not editing the XML directly but filling the corresponding attribute field in design mode). I'll have to find out what "syntetic imports are.

Comment: I forgot to mention that AS does indeed recognize the error in the XML, I guess, because the (mistyped) function name is show in red, and there is a small red exclamation point shown in the top right corner. It is just that the "tab" does not have the red underline and the project is build w/o problem, which surprised me.

Comment: yeah I understood what you meant @phunsoft , unfortunately nothing i could think of  could create a scenario where you would get a compile time error, but you could avoid this entirely by using synthetic functions to set your listeners, like i said in my answer :)

Comment: @phunsoft i've updated my answer to include a basic example of what i was talking about, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for adding that example. So, I understand that with synthetic imports I can just refer to any recourse defined in the R.java files without the need to „find...() it first.

Comment: yes, kotlin allows us to "import" the entire view to where we'll need it, without having to do a `find` reference for it. there are a few situations where you'll still need to use a "root" to find the view you're looking for, but this is a bit advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

In layout which you are importing in your Activity,
place onClick() in the element and refrence it to the Activity where you imported onClick listner android:onClick="onClick"

[image]

Comment: You misunderstood the questions. Because of the typo in the XML, then function name ("onClick" in your example) in the XML did not match the function name in the Kotlin code file. It all works fine when I correct the typo. The problem is that Android Studio does *not* point out that the the reference from the XML file cannot be resolved in the code file(s).

Comment: Yes , Android Studio does not point out that the reference from the XML, we have to  make it sure from our side when we refrence.